# Max-Min and Min-Min algorithms implementation

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, jobs

I'm trying to simulate the Max-Min and Min-Min scheduling algorithms and code them myself in a simulation. But don't really understand how to implement the way they work in code.

For example, in FCFS algorithm i use 3 servers(vms),each server is faster than the other and 5 tasks with different arrival times. So the first task will check the first server and will be scheduled there, the second if arrive while the first is't completed yet, will check the availability and scheduled to the second server. If all 3 servers are occupied the next task will be scheduled to the one with the min remain executing time.

Now for the Min-Min and Min-Max this is the theoretical background:

Min-Min:
Phase 1: First computes the completion time of every task on each machine and then for every task select the machine which processes the tasks in minimum possible time.
Phase 2: Among all the tasks in Meta task the task with minimum completion time is selected and is assigned to machine on which minimum execution time is expected. The task is removed from the list of Meta Task and the procedure continues until Meta Task list is empty.

Max-Min:
Phase 1: First computes the completion time of every task on each machine and then for every task chooses the machine which processes the tasks in minimum possible time
Phase 2: Among all the tasks in Meta Task the task with maximum completion time is selected and is assigned to machine. The task is removed from the list of Meta Task and the procedure continues until Meta Task list is empty.

I get the phase 1 for both algorithms, I need to check the task's burst time and server's speedup -> burst/speedup = execution time. I will find the best server for each task.
But I can't understand the phase 2. For Min-Min i have to choose every time the fastest task and when i find it I will have to schedule it to the faster server. But the workload will be imbalanced, as I said 3 servers and at least one is the faster, lets say server with ID 1, so every time the tasks will scheduled to this one, I also need the other 2 to work.

Same problem with Max-Min, find the worst task, schedule it to the worst server, but only one server is the worst so the other 2 will not work. How am I suppose to do the balancing and also take in consideration that the tasks arrive in different times?

If you need anything more just let me know and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find nice description of both algorithms in:

- [User-Priority Guided Min-Min Scheduling Algorithm For Load Balancing in Cloud Computing](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236346423_User-Priority_Guided_Min-Min_Scheduling_Algorithm_For_Load_Balancing_in_Cloud_Computing)
- [A Comparative Analysis of Min-Min and Max-Min Algorithms based on the Makespan Parameter](http://www.ijarcs.info/index.php/Ijarcs/article/download/3151/3127):

I paste here pseudocode for Min-Min. ET<sub>ij</sub> is execution time for task t<sub>i</sub> on resource R<sub>j</sub>. And r<sub>j</sub> is ready time of R<sub>j</sub>.

[image]

That's true that you can have imbalanced load, because all small task will get executed first. Max-Min algorithm overcomes this drawback.

> Max-Min algorithm performs the same steps as the Min-Min algorithm but the main difference comes in the second phase, where a task t<sub>i</sub> is selected which has the maximum completion time instead of minimum completion time as in min-min and assigned to resource R<sub>j</sub>, which gives the minimum completion time.

Comment: Ok this helped a lot, but still let's say for Min-Min the fastest task will choose the fastest server, so the first server will be occupied with this one. The second fast task should wait for this server to finish or should I schedule to the next fast available server? So the other 2 servers will also work.

Comment: @Sentinel There are two different concepts: *execution time* (ET) and *completion time* (CT). You assign to the server with minimum CT. Then you recompute CTs, and CTs on the server which just got assigned a task will increase. So, next time you might find the smallest CT on another server.

Comment: So the arrival times are useful only for calculate waiting and turn around time on these algorithms? Because the pseudocode  speaks of tasks in metatask queue. That means that all the tasks until the last arrived and they are waiting to be scheduled, so we don't care about the arrival time right now, right?

So lets say Task 1 Burst 6 Arrival 0, Task 2 Burst 4 Arrival 1. So Task 2 should scheduled to server one because of CT 4 and not Task 1 even if got here earlier right? It's like this algorithm getting all people in line and then serve them,don't care who was here earlier right?

Comment: @Sentinel Yes, we don't care about arrival time. At any moment of time we care only about tasks which are already in the queue. In your example at time 0 we have only one task in the queue, and so this task is scheduled.

Comment: @Sentinel you can imagine that you have two threads, one does scheduling every time a server has become available and second one inserts new tasks in the queue upon their arrival.

Comment: Sorry for asking much but my professors instructions are to not use threads, that's why I'm confused on how to simulate with simple coding. So I just need to schedule first the tasks and then calculate waiting and turn around time. I think I got it now, first schedule without considering arrival time, then calculate timers in each vm and done right?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what is *vm*, so i will propose you a solution without threads. You can create an event queue (something like min heap, so you can extract the closest event in time). There are two types of events - *task arrival* (T) and *server has become available* (S). First, you populate the queue with arrival times, then every time you assign a task to a server you add corresponding S event (the task has finished which happens on its CT) to the event queue. Now, on every S event you reschedule and assign a task.

Comment: VM is the server. Thanks for the proposition I will consider it and maybe make some changes. I will close this question as answered, you helped a lot.